# Getting data from store actions in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, store, nuxt.js

I'm trying to learn vue.js, nuxt, and how to use the store all at once. I'm slowly getting what to do, but I think the store is a bit more complicated then I expected.

So I'm trying to render a list of "pages" from an array. Right now it's just an object from the code, but I'd like to later on replace with a http request to get similar data from the server.

```
const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        pages: [],
        groups: []
      },
      mutations: {
        getPages(state, data) {
            state.pages = data;
        }
      },
      actions: {
          fetchData({ commit }) {
              commit('getPages', {
                  1: { 'name': 'index' },
                  2: { 'name': 'search' } 
              })
      }
    })
  }

  export default createStore
```

This, I think looks right. But I think my problem resides in the component code:

```
<template>
// pages/index.vue
    <li :for="page in pages">
        {{ page }}
      </li>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 computed: {
   pages() {
     return this.$store.state.pages
   }
 },
 methods: {
   getPages() {
     this.$store.commit('getPages')
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

This is obviously wrong, I'm getting the error:

```
Property or method "page" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First thing that pops to mind is that it's not `:for` but `v-for`. The second one is related to store and getters, but it's less of a problem as your code is ok and you should be getting data out of the store. Third, since you're using nuxt - you can just add a file to `store/` directory so you don't have to fiddle with `new Vuex.Store...`

Comment: Hi N.B on the last part, I'm doing exactly what it says in the docs. and isn't :for shorthand?

Comment: I have questions, did you executed "createStore"? Is your store included in your new Vue instance? I suggest you to use vue-devtools you can see whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I guessed right, your `this.$store.commit('getPages')` commits mutation  without payload, like `this.$store.commit('getPages', undefined)`. You should dispatch your action instead of commiting the mutation. `this.$store.dispatch('fetchData')`. And also create getter in Vuex:

```
      getters: {
         getPages(state) {
             return state.pages
         }
      }
```

Hope it will be helpful.